# C# Setup the amount of dimensions in an array in runtime

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to do something like this

```
int amountOfDimensions = 3;
Array a = new Array(3);
```

but of course that is not a thing in C#,
but is there's something that do the same thing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Array.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32___), e.g.

```
// array of int with 3 dimensions with correspondent lengths 2, 3 and 4:
// i.e. result will be int[2, 3, 4]
var result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 2, 3, 4);
```